# how to post url parameters to another postback file after saving

Tags: php, url, parameters, postback

I have a postback script that saves the incoming url parameters to a database.

e.g. http://myurl.com/postback.php?param1=123&param2=456

How can I send these parameters to another postback url after saving the parameters?
e.g. http://differenturl.com/postback.php?param1=123&param2=456

Thanks

James

Comment: try reading about PHP's `cURL` http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php using the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` flag. **And just to clarify**: I'm a bit confused. Do you want to send this in post data or get data?

Comment: Can't you simply do a `file_get_contents('http://differenturl.com/postback.php?param1=123&param2=456');` from the first callback url and then parse the parameters from the `$_GET` array at your second callback file?

Answer (score 2):

You basically have a few options here. Using the `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRINGS']` you can get all of the variables passed in the URL and then use that string in either a redirect, `file_get_contents` or a `cURL` request. Using the URL you've provided, with the `QUERY_STRINGS` key, you'd get the string `param1=123&param2=456`. You could then concat onto your new URL to use the `file_get_contents` function, `curl`, or a header redirect (if that's what you want).

```
$reqURL = "http://differenturl.com/postback?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

Alternatively if you wanted to use post, you'd pass `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRINGS']` under the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` flag.

I'm still confused which it is you want to do, send variables in a query string in the URL (GET) or post the data with the headers (POST) and make it not visible in the URL?